# DOMDocument programming: a lot of little dilemmas, how to solve them?

Tags: dom

I need elegance and performance: how to decide by the "best implementation" for each [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/) algorithm that I face. [This simple "DOMNodeList grouper"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/33719/24276) illustrate many little dilemmas:

- use `iterator_to_array` or "populate an array", when not all items need to be copied.
- use *clone* operator, *cloneNode* method or *import* method?
- use  `parentNode::method()` or `documentElement::method`? ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19749210/287948))
- first `removeChild` or first `replaceChild`, no avoids "[side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19710238/287948)"?
- ...

My position, today, is only "do an arbitrary choice and follow it in all implementations" (like a ["Convention over configuration" principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration))... But, **there are another considerations?  About performance, there are some article showing benchmarks?**

---

PS: this is a generic DOM question, any language (PHP, Javascript, Python, etc.) have the problem.

Comment: If your concerns are performance, the answer is always _test it_.  And the answer could be different per every combination of language/library(/browser for JS) anyway.

Comment: Yes, but my subquestion is  *"... there are some article showing benchmarks?"*.   I also think that the majority of implementations are using [LibXML2](http://xmlsoft.org/), so, will expect perfomance relations  be ~"language independent".